# Navigation menu works in chrome 28, breaks in chrome 29

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am experiencing a strange issue.

My horizontal navigation menu on my wordpress site uses ddsmoothmenu. You hover over the menu item and the dropdown displays more pages. This works fine in chrome 28.

I updated to chrome 29 and this no longer works. Instead, you have to click the menu item to see the drop down.

Does anyone know what has changed from chrome 28 > chrome 29 that would break this feature and the potential fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the HTML/CSS that is exhibiting the problem? Otherwise, it is difficult to answer.

Comment: +1, please provide a jsFiddle. and btw, ddsmoothmenu is a javascript menu ... might want to include javascript in the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ddsmoothmenu.js find

`smoothmenu.detecttouch? 'toggle'`

and replace it with

`smoothmenu.detecttouch? 'hover'`

It will work fine.